# How does compiler know which 'javax' to look for for swing since there are multiple javax packages?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

[image]

Actually I see multiple packages with javax (java,base.javax, java.compiler.javax). So, why dont we mention 'base' and 'compiler' in our import path? And how could compiler know that swing is in java.desktop.javax package and not in the others such as java.base.javax?

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Take the time to ask your question describe your problem in English, and include any relevant code in text in the question itself.

Comment: thanks. edited. can u please upvote now? I am not able to post new question

Comment: I still see a link to a code image.  Fix that.   If the code is relevant to the question, and necessary to make it an answerable question, put it into the question.  Otherwise, get rid of it.  Please read [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) which explains why you shouldn't to it and also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to know in which module (java.base, java.compiler, java.desktop) to look for the package `javax.swing`. It just looks into each module in the module path for the package `javax.swing`. The existence of a package `javax` in several modules is of no importance in itself (from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1)): _The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages [] but has no significance in itself_

Answer (score 2):

The package structure is just a fancy way of describing a directory structure.  If you specify a package `javax.swing.JFrame` to import, the classloader just looks for `javax/swing/JFrame.class` somewhere in your classpath.

If there are multiple versions of the class, the first one the class loader encounters is used (unless you have a fancy class loader, for instance in an EJB implementation or some custom implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Actually I see multiple packages with javax (java,base.javax, java.compiler.javax). So, why dont we mention 'base' and 'compiler' in our import path? And how could compiler know that swing is in java.desktop.javax package and not in the others such as java.base.javax?

Comment: The compiler knows where to look because you specify it in the import with the 'dot-path'.